# Propagating a list of icons on click based on a json autocomplete query

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an autocomplete using react-autosuggest from [here](http://react-autosuggest.js.org/). The autocomplete works and queries as expected. The part I am having trouble with is attaching or passing the query result to the top next to he heart icon. This will all make sense if you see my [**webpackBin example**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkfPUZx1-MYo9aC8zG-).

I tried passing the values from them new suggestion[ ] but, although it finds it and displays it in place, it doesn't stick. It clears it right back up as soon as I type something else or even mouseleave. I almost certain I have to create an empty array to collect them there, but I am drawing a blank.

This the function I created to retrieve the icons from the query

```
onSuggestionClick = suggestionName => this.setState({
    selectedSuggestion: suggestionName
});
```

in the render:

```
 const suggestionList =
    <div>
        {suggestions.map((suggestion, index) => (
            <FontIcon
                key={index}
                onClick={() => this.onSuggestionClick(suggestion)}>
                <i className="material-icons">{suggestion.icon}</i>
            </FontIcon>
        ))}
    </div>
```

and then the return call

```
{suggestionList}
```

I am building something similar somewhere else that works but in this particular component it doesn't. How can I make a list of icons based on the items chosen from the jspn that contains them?

Here is a screenshot of the desired effect I built in Angular
[image]

I need the same but I'm a ReactJS baby :)

Thanks in advance! Code is in the [**webpackBin**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkfPUZx1-MYo9aC8zG-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasnt 100% on what you were trying to accomplish, but it seems like you want a user to be able to search for favorites and add them to a div.It seems like you need another array to persist the actual selected suggestions. [I edited your jsfiddle-sorry if I overwrote your code](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KkwixkLufpdMODAU87h).  The problem is you're using the suggested array for two different things, persisting the state and passing in to the autocomplete library.  If you add another array to the state, you can persist your options in there in the onClick handler.

Comment: It looks great in the webpackbin! This will do fine. I'll credit you the answer as soon as it lets me